# How to make a single url host multiple websites?

Tags: web

I've noticed many sites use some strategy to host their two sites for pc and mobile users on only one url. For example, https://read.douban.com , its pc site and mobile site uses one url, how does this happen? Note I'm not asking the responsive design because its mobile site does use responsive design itself. And I don't think it is a nginx redirect because the urls are the same. There is one link on the mobile site to switch between the two sites. 
How does they make a single url host multiple websites? And how to switch between them? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are many ways. One way I know, is with [Struts](https://struts.apache.org/): Each request is going through Java logic and then an JSP page is sent to the user {This is a **very** simplified way to look at Struts}.

So, in this case a request comes from a mobile browser - will get a JSP made for mobile. A request from a PC will get a JSP for PC. The URL can stay the same.

Comment: So the server will record this choice in session, to keep the choice persistence during this session's lifetime? And when user click the switching url the server will change this choice?

Comment: So the server will record this choice in session, to keep the choice persistence during this session's lifetime? And when user click the switching url the server will change this choice and rerender current controller action?

Comment: Yes.session or cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the user request then you can hosting a single url to multiple websites?

So First detect the user request.
NB: I only consider the incoming user request is from PC or other devices(Phone, Tab, etc..)

STEP 01: request is from PC

```js
// return negative value if the request is from PC
var myNavigator = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile");
```

So, based on `myNavigator` value, we make separate sites.
Tnx, Happy coding!